# Why is SKTextureAtlas(dictionary:) Crashing

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, sktextureatlas

I am using the following code to create a texture atlas at runtime using a single .png image sprite sheet:

```
func createSpriteTextureAtlas(atlasNumber atlas:Int, forWorld world:Int) {
        //load the png file
        let image = UIImage(named: "world\(world)_spritesheet\(atlas)_2048x2048.png")
        //create the dictonary
        var imageDictionary = [String: UIImage]()
        //iterate through all rows and columns and get the subimage
        var imageIndex = 0
        for row in 0...7 {
            for column in 0...7 {
                let sourceRect = CGRect(x:column * 256, y:row * 256, width:256, height:256)
                let sourceImage = image?.cgImage!.cropping(to: sourceRect)
                let subImage = UIImage(cgImage: sourceImage!)
                //add the sub image and name to the dictionary
                imageDictionary["\(imageIndex)"] = subImage
                imageIndex = imageIndex + 1
            }
        }
        //create the texture atlas using the dictionary
        spriteTextureAtlas[atlas] = SKTextureAtlas(dictionary: imageDictionary)
    }
```

I have a different sprite sheet for every world. I made all the sprite sheets myself using the same tool. This code works 100% of the time for most images.

For some images however, the program crashes at: SKTextureAtlas(dictionary: imageDictionary) with the error: Thread 4: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x105ff2000). The stack trace says it is crashing inside: #0 0x00000002178e2d34 in -[SKTextureAtlasPacker isFullyOpaque:] ().

The crash does not happen every time and only happens for some images. The crash never happens on the simulator. All 64 entries in the dictionary contain a valid name/UIImage pair.

Did I make a mistake inside createSpriteTextureAtlas or is this a SpriteKit bug?

P.S. I already know that I can let XCode make the texture atlas for me by using a folder with a .atlas extension but this is not what i want to do.

This code works 100% of the time for most of my sprite sheets. The crash only happens on a few sprite sheets and not every time. The images are mostly the same: same tool, same file format, same size, etc. The issue occurs with png and bmp files.

I did see this: [SKTextureAtlas EXC_BAD_ACCESS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62136134/sktextureatlas-exc-bad-access) and took a look at the solution but making changes to the files and trying different tools and compression levels did not help. It just seems as though SpriteKit SKTextureAtlas(dictionary:) fails with some png files.

Comment: can you post an example png that generates the bug?

Comment: I cannot add the image. StackOverflow gives me an error: Failed to upload image; an error occurred on the server

Comment: frequently people link to images remotely via imgur or even github. but my guess is that there's an idiosyncrasy about some of your png files .. a weird pixel dimension, or it got encoded weird. even a bad filename might do it. but we can't help without having the offending image on hand to test with ;)

Comment: Thank you for the tip about using imgur. The link is: https://imgur.com/mvtmEGI

Comment: @Fault: I understand that you think it may be something odd about the file or filename. I agree. The issue is that it does not crash all the time which makes no sense to me. The fact that it never fails in the simulator also makes it odd.

Comment: thanks. i *can* reproduce the problem -- it crashes more than half the time on device. good news tho, i just converted it to gif then back to png and the crash goes away `sips -s format gif mvtmEGI.png --out mvtmEGI.gif; sips -s format png mvtmEGI.gif --out mvtmEGI_fixed.png`

Comment: i realize your original question is "why?" not "how can i fix it?" ;) so, yes, i think the answer is you've found a bug. and if you feel so moved, you should submit a bug report which includes the offending sample image